# Kotlin shortify String with triple dot

Tags: kotlin

Is it a native method in Kotlin like take but add "..." at the end if it's more long than the param ?

I wrote this :

```
fun String.takeDot(limite:Int) = if(limite < 3 || this.length <= limite) this else this.take(limite-3) + "..."

fun main() {
    println("test".takeDot(5))//test
    println("testaedad".takeDot(5))//tes...
}
```

Comment: No, that's way too specific to be a standard library function. It’s only useful for monospaced font faces and certain locales, and a specific strategy for displaying truncated text. Did you know there's an ellipsis character in Unicode?

Comment: No I didn't know for the caracter in Unicode. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Your custom top-function does a great job you don't need any another